# Java Google Drive Android API, get file ID after upload

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I'm using Google Drive Android API.
Here is my problem : after uploaded a file (image.png), I need the file id (to build an URL for my database). But after many days of research (Google, documentation) i can't find a solution. Many people talk about the REST API or about the older version (depreciated) of the Google Drive Android API.

Here is my main page to upload file :

```
package eu.epitech.tuto;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.*;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.widget.DataBufferAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.io.*;

public class ReportAnIssueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int GET_FROM_GALLERY = 3;

    private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;

    private DataBufferAdapter<Metadata> mResultsAdapter;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_an_issue);
        mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
        signIn();
    }

    public void importPicture(View view) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
    }

    private void buildIssue(String url) {
        System.out.println("URL:" + url);

        /* Comment because i can't have my url */

        /*EditText text = findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        String pos = longitude + ":" + latitude;
        addIssueToBdd(text.getText().toString(), url, "Anonymous", null, pos);*/
    }

    private void createIssue() {
        saveFileToDrive();
    }

    private void createPictureFile(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        String filename = "mytmp";
        File f = new File(getCacheDir(), filename);
        if (!f.createNewFile())
            return;

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

    private void addIssueToBdd(String title, String pictureUrl, String owner, String date, String location) {
        Bdd bdd = new Bdd("tuto");
        Issue issue = new Issue(title, pictureUrl, owner, date, location);
        bdd.addIssue(issue);
    }

    /**
     * Start sign in activity.
     */
    private void signIn() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Start sign in");
        GoogleSignInClient GoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
        startActivityForResult(GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }

    /**
     * Build a Google SignIn client.
     */
    private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;

        mDriveResourceClient
                .createContents()
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.", e))
                .continueWithTask(task -> createFileIntentSender(task.getResult(), image));
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@link IntentSender} to start a dialog activity with configured {@link
     * CreateFileActivityOptions} for user to create a new photo in Drive.
     */
    private Task<Void> createFileIntentSender(DriveContents driveContents, Bitmap image) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
        // Get an output stream for the contents.
        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
        // Write the bitmap data from it.
        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
        try {
            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.", e);
        }

        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
        // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet =
                new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/png")
                        .setTitle("issue.png")
                        .build();
        // Set up options to configure and display the create file activity.
        CreateFileActivityOptions createFileActivityOptions =
                new CreateFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(driveContents)
                        .build();
        return mDriveClient
                .newCreateFileActivityIntentSender(createFileActivityOptions)
                .continueWith(task -> {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(task.getResult(), REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    return null;
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in request code");
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signed in successfully.");
                    mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
                    mDriveResourceClient =
                            Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                Log.i(TAG, "capture image request code");
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image captured successfully.");
                    mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                    image.setImageBitmap(mBitmapToSave);
                    createIssue();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                mBitmapToSave = null;
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Here the file can be not yet uploded...
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clears the result buffer to avoid memory leaks as soon
     * as the activity is no longer visible by the user.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

I need use the Google Drive Android APi, can you help me to get the file ID ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the `fileID` upon successful upload of the file.

Here is a sample code in the [Google document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads):

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your answer, but your example use the GoogleDrive REST API, not the Android API. That can't help me :/

Comment: Have you tried using `driveFile.getDriveId()` in the `OnSuccessListener`? Try checking this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file)

Comment: Hello, i dont have a driveFile variable... You can see all my source code at the first post.